# cv2.findCountours returns twice as many contours for one shape

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have distinct 12 shapes in my image that I have created with paint, but cv2.findCountours returns 24 contours. Why is that the case? I did not find any answers elsewhere.

Here is my test image:
[test.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCp8S.png)
You can clearly see there are 12 shapes.
When I loop through contours, I get 24 shapes

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('test.png')
edges = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    print(area)

while (1):

    cv2.imshow("Original", image)
    cv2.imshow("Edges", edges)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Console returns:

```
935.0
913.0
4301.0
4271.0
6610.5
6579.0
2651.5
2639.5
11113.0
11070.5
6317.0
6271.0
2259.0
2237.0
4003.0
3981.0
13303.0
13208.0
16580.0
16511.5
6638.5
6594.0
7541.5
7527.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) says:

> CV_RETR_TREE retrieves all of the contours and reconstructs a full
> hierarchy of nested contours. This full hierarchy is built and shown
> in the OpenCV contours.c demo.

In this case, for your each contour, it detects 2 array of contours: one is outer the other is inner. Your problem will be fixed if you replace the line with:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

> CV_RETR_EXTERNAL retrieves only the extreme outer contours. It sets
> hierarchy[i][2]=hierarchy[i][3]=-1 for all the contours.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread("1.png")
imgGrey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(imgGrey, 245, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(img,[i],-1, (255, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("selected area",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:
[image]
are denoted by sky color